# Maven not adding "Authorization" header

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to deploy artifacts to a protected by Basic Auth repository.

I specify

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>some.repo</id>
        <name>Some Repository</name>
        <url>https://foo.bar</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

in `pom.xml`

And

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>some.repo</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>{encoded password}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

in `settings.xml`

But when I run `mvn deploy` it fails with the error: `Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:. -> [Help 1]`

If I use

```
 <server>
  <id>some.repo</id>
    <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
            <property>
                <name>Authorization</name>
                <value>Basic (hash)</value>
            </property>
        </httpHeaders>
    </configuration>
</server>
```

instead - it works.

After inspection with Wireshark I discovered that in the first scenario (with login/password) Maven doesn't add `Authorization` header to the HTTP request.

Is it correct behavior? Am I missing something in the configuration?

Comment: Frome where did you get the info for `<httpHeaders>/<property>/<name>/<value>`? According to the doc it'd rather be [`<httpHeaders>/<httpHeader>/<name>/<value>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html#HTTP_Headers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in this case, it was not Maven, but the server-side problem: server was not sending `Connection: keep-alive` header. With this header, the authorization flow works.

Comment: Well persistent connections is the default in HTTP/1.1 so it is debatable if it is a server-side problem. See section 8.1.2 from Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 RFC - https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt. _ A significant difference between HTTP/1.1 and earlier versions of
   HTTP is that persistent connections are the default behavior of any
   HTTP connection._

Answer (score 2):

maven will only send username/password on requests where server responds with a

status code:`401`

header: `WWW-Authenticate: Basic`.